# How to get data from another process in Contiki-NG?

Tags: contiki-ng

I try to send data from A process to B process with **contiki-NG** and **firefly**.

This is sender part of A process

```
 PROCESS_THREAD(A_process, ev, data)
{ 
  ...
    int data=1;
    if(process_post(&led_example, PROCESS_EVENT_CONTINUE, &data_led)!=PROCESS_ERR_OK){
       printf("event could not be posted\n");
    }
...
}
```

This is receiver part of B process

```
 PROCESS_THREAD(B_process, ev, data)
{ 
 ...
   if(ev==PROCESS_EVENT_CONTINUE ){
     printf("data=%d",*(int*)data);
   }
 ...
}
```

I checked event is delivered well.
But problem is the data.
I expected that B process print **"data=1"** but print garbage value (**"data=2118363"**).
(I know `process_data_t` is `void*`(void pointer))

How can I get right value?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try declaring like :

```
static int data_led;
```

Comment: It's been so long since I asked the question, I can't remember how I solved it. But your answer is very much appreciated.